# What function do I use for looking up how many times something occurs in a cell for each department?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Partial clip of my spreadsheet:

```
Dixon            Tamara      tmdixon2    Anthropology              SecurID 700
Portera          Maria       mportera    Anthropology              SecurID Software Token
Wallace          Beth        bethwall    Anthropology              SecurID Software Token
Hewitt           Lisa        lkhewitt    Art                       SecurID 700
Hewitt           Lisa        lkhewitt    Art                       SecurID Software Token
Koenig           Becky       bkoenig     Art                       SecurID 700
Koenig           Becky       bkoenig     Art                       SecurID Software Token
Moffitt          Margaret    mamoffit    Art                       SecurID Software Token
Otto             Keith       keo         Art                       SecurID 700
Otto             Keith       keo         Art                       SecurID Software Token
Swiatek          Deborah     dswiatek    Art                       SecurID Software Token
Leary            Kevin       krleary     Arts Management Program   SecurID Software Token
Dennison         Jeffrey     jdenn       Biological Sciences       SecurID Software Token
Helfer           Joseph      helfer      Biological Sciences       SecurID Software Token
Hollingsworth    Margaret    hollings    Biological Sciences       SecurID Software Token
```

I want to use a formula that counts the number of times 'SecurID Software Token' occurs for Anthropology, and the number of times 'SecurID 700' occurs for Anthropology, and so on for all departments.  What function do I use?

Comment: One solution is to add a helper column that contains a concatenation of the two columns.  Then count there.

Answer (score 0):

COUNTIFS would be my first suggestion since you can look for multiple matching criteria.  The easiest way, and what makes the most sense in my head reading your situation, is to have a summary section where you will already have your unique departments and SecurID items.  That part would be manual in my answer though.  I'm not sure how you could capture the entire picture for all departments and all items in each department dynamically, so your mileage may vary (YMMV).

Sample formula for screenshot below, for cell H5

```
=COUNTIFS($D$1:$D$15,G$4,$E$1:$E$15,G5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could produce a pivot table, using the data in these two columns :

[image]

This would produce the following pivot table :

[image]

Using these criteria :

[image]